# How to make PHP POST request work properly in CRUD API as layer for connecting to MySQL database?

Tags: php, rest, api, backend, crud

I cannot POST values to database via Postman.

Recently I started building CRUD api for practicing purposes. I have found few good tutorials on how to make connection to database with PHP. I managed to build MySQL DB with phpMyAdmin and to connect it with PHP. Also GET request is returning values from database:
http://ivanzarkovic.com/movies/fetch_all_movies.php

In Postman I have tried to add
http://ivanzarkovic.com/movies/add_movie.php?movie_name=SomeName&genre=SF&year=2005&rating=4.6
or bulk in JSON form.

I though that I am making mistake with type of data, so I've changed type in DB to string (VARCHAR), but it didn't solved problem.

```
if(isset($_POST['movie_name'])&&isset($_POST['genre'])&&isset($_POST['year'])&&isset($_POST['rating'])){
    $movieName = $_POST['movie_name'];
    $genre = $_POST['genre'];
    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $rating = $_POST['rating'];

    //Query to insert a movie
    $query = "INSERT INTO movies( movie_name, genre, year, rating) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
    //Some code here
}else{
    //Mandatory parameters are missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "missing mandatory parameters";
}
```

I am expecting to commit new entry to a database, but it is stuck to "missing mandatory parameters". isset($_POST['movie_name']) is returning false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example URL you provided has the data as query parameters.
This means you should be accessing `$_GET`, not `$_POST`.

Your code is correct for accepting the data via post, is can you share you postman request?

Example:

```php
if (isset($_GET['movie_name']) && isset($_GET['genre']) && isset($_GET['year']) && isset($_GET['rating'])) {
    $movieName = $_GET['movie_name'];
    $genre = $_GET['genre'];
    $year = $_GET['year'];
    $rating = $_GET['rating'];

    //Query to insert a movie
    $query = "INSERT INTO movies( movie_name, genre, year, rating) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
    //Some code here
} else {
    //Mandatory parameters are missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "missing mandatory parameters";
}
```

Comment: As I used Postman for the first time, hope this is what you ask me to send. For the record I selected POST as method and added key value pairs and clicked "Send" button. I suppose I am making mistake with it.

POST /movies/add_movie.php?movie_name=some andsf&amp;genre=sf&amp;year=2005&amp;rating=4.6 HTTP/1.1

Host: ivanzarkovic.com

Cache-Control: no-cache

Postman-Token: 545fb30d-1e92-5327-8717-857b78164b7b

Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----

WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

Comment: Are you by any chance adding them in the field for query params, rather than the post body?

Comment: You were right, I did not sent right POST request. I had no clue why it was not working, but I have managed to post data to DB. Is this way of connecting to database secure enough if I add only login auth with token?